# Use default settings.xml file instead of one in ~/.m2

Tags: maven, settings

Is there possibility for Maven to ignore `settings.xml` contained in `.m2` folder?

I want it to use default repository, but my laptop has configured development environment for other repositories and I don't want to lose these settings. What's more, these repositories have priority over repos in my `pom.xml` and fail if they can't download artifact.

What are the options? Should I choose other `settings.xml` file or is there option to use none?

Comment: First repositories in the pom file is a bad practice...furthermore does your `settings.xml` contain configuration for a repository manager which does not sound like that...

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to have a `settings.xml` in the `.m2` folder. If there is none Maven uses `<Maven installation folder>/conf/settings.xml`, which has everything commented out by default.

See also [Settings Reference, Quick Overview](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Quick_Overview):

> There are two locations where a `settings.xml` file may live:
>
> - The Maven install: `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml`
> - A user’s install: `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`

You can use [custom settings files with the command line options](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-custom-locations-option):

> **-s,--settings** 
>     Alternate path for the user settings file
>
> **-gs, --global-settings** 
>     Alternate path for the global settings file

And, BTW, `.m2` is not the Maven home. It's the folder for [user-specific configuration and local repository](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/installation-sect-details.html#installation-sect-user). I corrected the question's title acordingly.